# Cant connect to mongo db

Tags: mongodb

Any idea why I am not able to connect to the mongo database?
I just installed it on a new debian following this https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-mongodb-on-debian-9/.

*Mongo startup logs:* https://hastebin.com/iyelaxasec.md

I issued `mongo` and get:

```
baseUser@vmd54274:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.19
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-06-17T01:53:05.338+0200 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
```

I didnt change any setting so everything should be running on the correct port. And I checked that the port is used by the service.

This is from lsof:

```
mongod     8898   mongodb   11u  IPv4 2530915      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:27017 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Add the output of `cat /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` to your question.

Comment: @NasirRiley I already did. Thats the hastebin link

Comment: Add them while you are trying to connect. Do not post images of text. Use the codeblocks to put them into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the issue myself. Appearently there was a flaw in my firewall configuration preventing access from localhost to mongodb